# QGraphicsItem - Item transformation fail

Tags: c++, qt, transformation, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I am having a rectangle that is used within a `QGraphicsItem`. Item is added to a scene and it has a pre-defined transformation, so that it maps the rectangle correctly. It was so far so good:

```
QRectF rect;    
QTransform transform;    
QGraphicsPolygonItem box;

box.setTransform(transform);    
box.setPolygon(rect);

qDebug() << rect;
qDebug() << transform;
qDebug() << transform.map(rect.topLeft());
qDebug() << transform.map(rect.topRight());
qDebug() << transform.map(rect.bottomRight());
qDebug() << transform.map(rect.bottomLeft());
qDebug() << transform.map(rect);
qDebug() << box.polygon();
qDebug() << box.scenePos();
```

outputs:

```
QRectF(34.2629,5.75334 40.4797x55.5691)
QTransform(type=TxProject, 11=8.39145 12=3.651e-16 13=-3.79358e-18 21=-11.232 22=1.24517 23=-0.00673223 31=731.81 32=58.3479 33=0.684533)
QPointF(1478.33, 101.443)
QPointF(2004.32, 101.443)
QPointF(2466.86, 495.792)
QPointF(1216.62, 495.792)
QPolygonF(QPointF(1478.33, 101.443) QPointF(2004.32, 101.443) QPointF(2466.86, 495.792) QPointF(1216.62, 495.792) QPointF(1478.33, 101.443) )
QPolygonF(QPointF(34.2629, 5.75334) QPointF(74.7427, 5.75334) QPointF(74.7427, 61.3225) QPointF(34.2629, 61.3225) QPointF(34.2629, 5.75334) )
QPointF(1069.06, 85.2375)
```

as expected; everything works fine; both vertices and the item itself are transformed right, that I can check all with `map` function. This worked fine for at least 40 different transforms.

However, for just another transformation matrix I encountered this interesting result:

```
QRectF(29.8193,9.86656 29.6347x43.7413)
QTransform(type=TxProject, 11=-4.51027 12=2.57144e-16 13=-1.00432e-19 21=7.88867 22=0.184078 23=0.00360371 31=-511.257 32=-69.1552 33=-0.353853)
QPointF(1784.23, 211.56)
QPointF(2204.16, 211.56)
QPointF(2218.99, 369.009)
QPointF(1387.07, 369.009)
QPolygonF(QPointF(0, 0) )
QPolygonF(QPointF(29.8193, 9.86656) QPointF(59.454, 9.86656) QPointF(59.454, 53.6079) QPointF(29.8193, 53.6079) QPointF(29.8193, 9.86656) )
QPointF(1444.83, 195.435)
```

***the vertices are transformed successfully; but the rect item couldn't. It outputs (0, 0) for the transformation.***

I thought this must be a bug in the framework, as it transforms a point fine but it just couldn't transform the items (I am also having lots of ellipses, rects couldn't be transformed). But when I try to reproduce I couldn't; it happens only with this matrix.

Since `map()` doesnt work, `item.setTransform()` – which I suppose using `map()` internally – also doesnt. Item does not show up on the scene.

For a clear vision I attached the second matrix (transposed) here.[image]

What am I doing wrong here ? Precision bug ? 32-bit issues ?

EDIT: digging down the [source](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/57756e72adf2081137b97f0e689dd16c770d10b1:src/gui/painting/qtransform.cpp#L1390), seems like `map` uses different approach for different types like `QPointF`, `QLineF`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging down the [bugs](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-9274), it seems like negative w value is not supported for transformations, and this is the problem I am facing with, since `w = m13.px + m23.py + m33` is negative for the 2nd matrix.

Multiplying the matrix with -1 fixed the bug.

Qt docs should really mention about this.